# Protocols can inherit from classes?

Tags: swift

I wrote these lines in the playground and I don't get any compile error:

```
class A {}
protocol B : A {}
```

How is possible a protocol is inheriting from a class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not really *inheriting* the protocol from that class. That syntax is saying that the protocol `B` can only be conformed to, by `A` or subclasses of `A`.

Here are some examples:

```
class C : A {}
class D {}

extension A : B {} // works
// or
// extension C : B {} // works


extension D : B {} // error
```

Answer (score 0):

This indicates that protocol B requires conforming types to be A or a subclass of A. Protocols are not concrete types themselves; they just provide rules that concrete conforming types my obey.